how to solve this massege in anacoda '' ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.tf_silent'''
I chose the spyder option to run the python code from Anaconda. Now I am facing this error.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.tf_silent'
Meanwhile, the cmd page opens for me, but I cannot type anything.
I want to run my code
